# Forcing exim to use a single address when sending email

Tags: exim

My ISP requires my sender envelope header, and from: header to be a specific address. How do I configure exim to force all email to have this address when relaying?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have fairly standard routers/transports. Simply modify the transport that is used for outbound mail to perform address rewriting:

```
remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  headers_rewrite = *@+local_domains newaddress@example.com fsr
  return_path = newaddress@example.com
```

The first rule will handle From/Sender/Reply-To and the second Return-Path.

You can replace `+local_domains` with a wildcard if you really wish.